# How to specify execute permissions of scripts using Python Setuptools

Tags: python, scripting, permissions, setuptools

I have a Python package that I've created and I'm using `setuptools.setup()` to install it. The package includes executable scripts, which use the `scripts` parameter of the `setup()` function.

I'm installing like this:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

After installation, the executable scripts are located in `/usr/local/bin`. The only problem is that the permissions are:

```
-rwxr-x---  1 root root   57 Aug 23 15:13 example_script*
```

Instead of:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   57 Aug 23 15:13 example_script*
```

Anybody know either how I can specify the permissions of the output executables or why the default isn't allowing anyone to execute?

FYI:
My umask is `0027` and the permission of `/usr/local/bin/` is `drwxr-xr-x` (owner=root group=root). All executable scripts have `-rwxr-xr-x` permissions in the development area.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question is a bit old by now, but I hope my answer will be useful to anyone who happens to find it just as I did.

I've had the same problem with my package. Apparently, neither setuptools nor pip (my pip is `1.5.6`) handle permissions explicitly. Your option is either change permissions manually, or migrate from `scripts` parameter to `entry_points`.

### 1) Change file permissions manually

This is tricky and kludgy enough, but should work. The idea is, if the installation process puts your executable to `/usr/local/bin`, it also has permissions to chmod the file to include executable flags. From `setup.py`, after your `setup()` clause, run something like:

```
execpath = '/usr/local/bin/yourexec'

if os.name is 'posix' and os.path.exists(execpath):
    os.chmod(execpath, int('755', 8))
```

### 2) Migrate to `entry_points`

setuptools offers an option for your `setup()` named `entry_points`. It accepts a dictionary with keys `console_scripts` and `gui_scripts`, which you can use as follows:

```
setup(
    # Package name, version, author, links, classifiers, etc
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'myexecfile = mypackage.mymainmodule:mymainfunction'
        ]
    }
)
```

This statement will automatically generate `myexecfile` executable which calls `mymainfunction` from `mymainmodule` of `mypackage`, which can easily be the package you're distributing.

The catch you should know is that entry point functions (`mymainfunction` in this example) may not have any arguments. If you passed `sys.argv` to your main function from your executable as an argument, you should rewrite the function to retrieve and parse `sys.argv` by itself.

Chris Warrick wrote a good article on this feature called [Python Apps The Right Way](https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2014/09/15/python-apps-the-right-way-entry_points-and-scripts/), you might find it useful.

Comment: I appreciate the formatting and effort that went into the answer, even if I can't tell whether it is correct.

Comment: Changing the file permissions manually of course works, but the second option doesn't work. Entry points is a clever tool for setuptools, but it doesn't change the nature of the permissions of installed binaries.

Comment: @nic Interesting, because I just tried to reproduce this error with `sudo pip install` and instead got an opposite result: entry point executable had x flags, `scripts` executable didn't. [Read the typescript of my Vagrant session](https://gist.github.com/bacondropped/f5ef979015818b3bd7f1) for details. My advice would be to stick to ep executables and foolproof it with chmod just in case.

Comment: Hmmm, nothing is consistent for me. I hate the idea of using chmod manually. Different setuptools, pip, and python are all causing variances here. Very lame.